# List the year when the table was dropped

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have these tables:

```
SUMMERGAMES (sg_gameno [PK], sg_year) 
GAME-DISCIPLINE ( discipline_code[PFK], sg_gameno[PFK] )
DISCIPLINE (discipline_code, discipline_name)
```

I need to list the discipline code and discipline name of those disciplines that ran in 2004 but did not run in 2008 or 2012. I also need to list the year it was dropped, i.e., (2008 or 2012) the first year it did not appear.

I used MINUS operator to solve the first part. But I do not know how to list the year it was dropped.

Comment: I have just edited your topic title to make it more explicit. Since it will help others while searching for similar question. Google search engine has indexing based on search counts, so better to mention an appropriate topic title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using aggregation and getting the *maximum* year something was around and whether it was around in 2004?

```
select d.discipline_code, d.displine_name,
       max(sg.sg_year) as lastYearRan,
       max(sg.sg_year) + 4 as firstYearDropped
from summergames sg join
    gamediscipline gd
    on sg.sg_gameno = gd.sg_gameno join
    discipline d
    on gd.discipline_code = d.discipline_code
group by d.discipline_code, d.displine_name
having sum(case when sg.sg_year = 2004 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when sg.sg_year in (2008, 2012) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause has two conditions.  The first says that the discipline ran in 2004.  The second says it didn't run in 2012 -- so was presumably dropped in 2008 or 2012.

Each condition in the `having` clause is counting the number of matching rows.  For instance, the first condition is counting the number of rows that have a year of 2004.  The `> 0` is requiring that there be at least one.  Similarly the second counts the number of rows where the discipline has a year of 2008 or 2012.  The `= 0` requires that there be no such records.

Comment: Thank you, but in the result I also got the games that [run in 2008 and dropped in 2012] which should not be in result!

Comment: @Marwa . . . Just change the condition `= 2012' to `in (2008, 2012)`.  However, in this case, all the drop years will be 2008.

Comment: Awesome :D thanks a lot .. Is working :) But I don't really understand how the max aggression and having sum case work for this question? If u can explain for me please

Comment: You used max(sg.sg_year) + 4 thats why i got year dropped 2008, if used max(sg.sg_year) + 8 will show year dropped is 2012. So, basically i am not getting the year dropped from the data i have in summergames table. Which may cause wrong result!

Comment: @Marwa . . . Your previous comment said that you don't want any games that run in 2008 and are dropped in 2012.  Hence, you are always getting 2008.

Comment: Make sense :)What about if i use MIN not MAX? I notice that min will display 2000 for the year then i need to plus 8, while max display 2004 and i need to add 4. How does the query display the min 2000 while i have in my data 1988? Same thing for max , why it show max is 2004?